# Powershell & Excel: How can I delete (xlshiftleft) a cell in a range if the cell contains a specific character

Tags: excel, powershell

I have seen many examples where I can delete an entire row if a cell contains a specific character or is blank, but I cannot find a way of deleting just that cell.

I can replace the character with:

```
$worksheet7.Range("D2:D1001").Replace("0","")
```

But I would prefer to delete the cell that contains the character

Answer (score 0):

Though we can clear it, I was not able to find a method to delete and shift a cell with the EPPlus library, including through the popular ImportExcel PowerShell module. It looks like we can delete a whole row or column, but not the specific cell.

You can however do this with Com automation. You can replace "ABCXYZ" with the character you wish to find.

```
# Find all cells with search text:
$searchText = "ABCXYZ"

# Create an instance of the Excel application
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\tmp\Book1.xlsx")

# Select the desired worksheet
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets["sheet1"]

#Find the first instance of the search text
$range = $worksheet.UsedRange
$FirstFind = $range.Find($searchText)
$FoundCells = $FirstFind

# Loop through until we've found all hits, stopping once we see the first result again.
$FoundCells = do {    
    $FoundCells = $range.FindNext($FoundCells)
    Write-Host "Found $searchText at cell: $($FoundCells.Address(0,0))"
    $FoundCells 
}
until ($FirstFind.Address(0, 0) -eq $FoundCells.Address(0, 0))

# Loop through all found cells
foreach ($Cell in $FoundCells) {
    #Delete the and shift the remaining cells to the left
    $CellAddress = $Cell.Address(0, 0)
    $range = $worksheet.Range($CellAddress)
    Write-Host "Deleting cell: $CellAddress"
    $range.Delete([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection]::xlShiftToLeft) | Out-Null
}

# Save and close the workbook (optional)
$workbook.Save()
$workbook.Close()

# Quit the Excel application
$excel.Quit()
```